# ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5

I tempt to change my code with your instructions but don't work :/

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

//stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,test);

/*function test(e:KeyboardEvent){
    trace('code='+e.keyCode);
}
*/
//--- Variables: ---
stop();

var timer1: Timer=new Timer (115000,1);
var timerPoint: Timer=new Timer (115000,0);
var points: Number = 0;

pisteWWRY = lvl1WWRY.play(); // Play the music

stage.addChild(map);

var tableau1: Array=[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                     [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],                         
                     [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]];                                    //Arr   ay to create level.

var L:int=0;
var C:int=0;

// création du tableau.

function lvl1 () {
    for (L=0; L<tableau1.length ;L++){                          
        for(C=0; C<tableau1[0].length ;C++){                    
            if (tableau1[L][C]==1){
                var Blockn1: block=new block(); 
                    map.addChild(Blockn1);
                    Blockn1.x=1620+C*60;
                    Blockn1.y=30+L*50;  
                    Blockn1.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisions);
                    stage.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, lvl1 );
            }
        }
    }
}

//--- Ecouteurs: ---

timer1.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER, stoplvl1);
timer1.start();

timerPoint.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER, pointlvl1);
timerPoint.start();

stage.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, moove);

//--- Fonctions: ---

function stoplvl1 (e:TimerEvent) :void{
    gotoAndStop(4);
}

function pointlvl1 (e:TimerEvent) :void{
    points++;
    Scorelvl1.text = points.toString();
}

function collisions (e:Event):void {
    if(e.target.hitTestObject(Perso)){
         if (map && stage.contains(map)) {
            stage.removeChild(map);
        }
        stage.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, moove);
        pisteWWRY = lvl1WWRY.stop();
        gotoAndStop(4);
    }
}
```

This is my code now. 
And my error:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: stop is not a function.
    at projsolo_fla::MainTimeline/collisions()[projsolo_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:78]
```

I don't go to the frame 4 and if I withdraws : pisteWWRY = lvl1.stop(); i crash when i do collisions ...

Comment: Where is map definition?

Answer (score 0):

In the `collisions` function you are removing the `map` from the stage but not stopping the `ENTER_FRAME` event that calls `collisions` so the second time it gets called `map` is no longer a child of the `stage` and you get the error.

You could do something like this

```
function collisions (e:Event):void {
    if(e.target.hitTestObject(Perso)){
        if (map && stage.contains(map)) {
            stage.removeChild(map);
        }
        stage.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, moove);
        stage.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, lvl1);
        playWWRY.removeEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, jouerWWRY);
        pisteWWRY = lvl1WWRY.stop();
        gotoAndStop(4);
    }
}
```

which will alleviate the problem, but I think you should rethink some of your code logic as that function is going to keep running until you remove the `ENTER_FRAME` event listener (which you can't even easily access anymore since it is no longer in scope).

Comment: If I try to do: Blockn1.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisions); don't work because Blockn1 doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, because as I pointed out it's no longer in scope because you are defining it inside of an `if` block.

You can try `(e.target).removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisions);`

Comment: You should turn on debugging to more easily see where the errors are happening. In the Flash IDE, go to `File -> Publish Settings -> Advanced` and click on `Permit debugging`. That will show you the line number where the errors are happening.

Comment: I put (e.target...); on the function collisions but i have this error ...TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at projsolo_fla::MainTimeline/collisions()

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure you don't want to be calling the lvl1 function on ENTER_FRAME, don't you just want to call it once? I also don't see the "moove" function defined anywhere so I don't know if you are trying to remove the map from the stage there as well.

Comment: with the debugging : TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at projsolo_fla::MainTimeline/collisions()[projsolo_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:80]

Comment: it's my :  playWWRY.removeEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, jouerWWRY);
 to stop the music .. ( don't work ... )

Comment: If I withdraws :playWWRY.removeEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, jouerWWRY);
pisteWWRY = lvl1WWRY.stop(); Software crash ...

Comment: My function moove :function moove (e:Event):void{
 map.x-=5;
} is to do scrool the map on the stage.

Comment: I don't even see 80 lines in what you pasted there (if that is indeed from frame3) so you need to go back and fix all the other errors as well which are outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I changed my lvl1 function, i call it when i go to the level's frame, one left ENTER_FRAME.